# Error when compiling Brackets Shell standalone app

Tags: adobe-brackets, brackets-shell

I have a web app that I'm trying to package up into a standalone app using Brackets-Shell. I followed the instructions here to setup Brackets and Brackets-Shell on my Mac OSX system:

https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-brackets-shell
http://clintberry.com/2013/html5-desktop-apps-with-brackets-shell/

When I run "grunt full-build" the process stops with this error message:

```
Running "stage-mac" task
>> cp: xcodebuild/Release/my_test.app: No such file or directory
Warning: Task "stage-mac" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

Were "my_test.app" is the name I've given to the app I'm trying to create. It seems that Grunt never creates my_test.app, but it does create Brackets.app. I've edited the Gruntfile.js file in the "brackets-shell" folder per the instructions in the previously mentioned link.

Anyone run into this problem, or have any ideas on how I can resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to change the app name in *appshell_config.gypi* to match the *Gruntfile.js* change you made. You'll need to rerun `grunt setup` after doing so.

Comment: Excellent! That was the missing piece of the puzzle for me. Thank you so much for your help. I can now package up my web app with Brackets Shell, and it runs as a native app on my Mac. Thanks again.

Comment: cohoman: Great! Feel free to upvote the answers too if you think they're good enough (though it's not required).

Comment: Also: I posted comments for these two corrections on the blog post you've linked to above. But they're not visible yet since they're still awaiting manual moderation by the blog owner...